# Upload Photos in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello i have the code below to upload pictures for my application. I will like to add a line or more to this code that will display a success message like this"Picture has been  uploaded successfully"

I know i will need to add a label control to display the message but i dont know how to go about. Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class PhotoAdmin_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        UserIdValue.Text = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()
        cannotUploadImageMessage.Visible = False

    End Sub


    Protected Sub dvPictureInsert_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvPictureInsert.ItemInserted
        'If the record was successfully inserted, save the picture
        If e.AffectedRows > 0 Then
            'Determine the maximum pictureID for this user
            Dim results As DataView =
                CType(maxPictureIDDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), 
                    DataView)

            Dim pictureIDJustAdded As Integer = CType(results(0)(0), Integer)

            'Reference the FileUpload control
            Dim imageUpload As FileUpload =
                CType(dvPictureInsert.FindControl("imageUpload"), FileUpload)

            If imageUpload.HasFile Then
                Dim baseDirectory As String = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/")

                imageUpload.SaveAs(baseDirectory & pictureIDJustAdded & ".jpg")
            End If

        End If
    End Sub



    Protected Sub dvPictureInsert_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles dvPictureInsert.ItemInserting
        Dim cancelInsert As Boolean = False


        Dim imageUpload As FileUpload =
            CType(dvPictureInsert.FindControl("imageUpload"), FileUpload)

        If Not imageUpload.HasFile Then
            cancelInsert = True
        Else
            If Not imageUpload.FileName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".JPG") Then
                cancelInsert = True 'Invalid image file!

            End If
        End If

        If cancelInsert Then
            e.Cancel = True
            cannotUploadImageMessage.Visible = True
        End If

        'Set the UserId value to the currently logged on user's ID
        e.Values("UserId") = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey

        'Set the UploadedOn value to the current date/time
        e.Values("UploadedOn") = DateTime.Now
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvPictures_RowDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeletedEventArgs) Handles gvPictures.RowDeleted
        Dim baseDirectory As String = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/")
        Dim fileName As String = baseDirectory &
            e.Keys("PictureID") & ".jpg"
        File.Delete(fileName)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Josh can you please help me with this. I have some few questions to ask but im kind of new in asp.net

Comment: Thank you the date/time has been updated. You are trully a blessing. Can u help me with this: I want the uploaded photo  to  display a success message like this"Picture has been uploaded successfully. Can u help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered thank God for this forum. It's really helpful, word cannot express it.
The answer is gotten from :

you have to display message in the "dvPictureInsert_ItemInserted" event. For more refernce please see this link , in this you can see the example section you can get what you have to do

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.iteminserted%28VS.80%29.aspx